# "... a risk that it exists or will exist" - Sentence Wording

Tags: pronouns, clauses

in the following piece of legislation, can you tell me if the correct grammar is being used?

"A person acts recklessly within the meaning of section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act 1971 with respect to -

a circumstance when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist.

I'm guessing "a circumstance" is the object of the preposition "to", but how is the remaining text ,  "when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist" behaving. As an adverb adjective clause phrase?

I've probably been very confusing, but your help is appreciated!

Comment: I put some of the words from your question into the title, because it normally makes a question more appealing in the questions queue, and makes it easier to find. If you preferred it the way it was you can just press on the 'edited' button and then "rollback" the edit on the following page. Alternatively, if you want to just get rid of the "Araucaria" under your post. Have an edit and fiddle with a full stop and my name will disappear!

Comment: [Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_v_G).

Answer (score 2):

> "A person acts recklessly within the meaning of section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act 1971 with respect to -
>
> (i) a circumstance when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist;
>
> (ii) a result when he is aware of a risk that it will occur;
>
> ... and it is, in the circumstances known to him, unreasonable to take the risk"

It would be easy to think that the phrase *that it exists or will exist* is an ungrammatical relative clause. It isn't though. It would also be easy to think that the word *it* in (i) refers to *a risk*. However, it does not.

The phrase *that it exists or will exist* is a content clause. It is the Complement of the word *risk*. We can see a similar example below:

- There's a risk that we won't finish the job on time.

The word *it* in (i) refers to *a circumstance*. The word *it* in (ii) refers to a result. So for these we get:

- a circumstance when he is aware of a risk that the circumstance exists or will exist
- a result when he is aware of a risk that the result will occur

So person acts recklessly, for example, with respect to a safety catch not being engaged (a circumstance) when they are aware of a risk that this catch is not engaged ("it"/ "the circumstance" exists) or that the catch will become unengaged (the circumstance will exist).

A person acts recklessly, for example, if they cause a fire (a result) when they were aware of a risk that the fire ("it" / "the result") would occur.

The sentence is perfectly grammatical so long as we understand what the pronoun *it* refers to in each case. The phrase "when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist" is a prepositional Adjunct (read Adverbial) in the larger sentence:

- A person acts recklessly within the meaning of section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act 1971 with respect to a circumstance [when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist].

It could be considered a *temporal* Adjunct. It describes the situations in which someone may be considered reckless with regard to a given circumstance. Notice that we could consider it as a type of conditional Adjunct too. It means something like "*if* he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist."

---

<sup>**Warning**:</sup>

<sup>This is my interpretation of the sentence. I am not a lawyer. Under no circumstances should this be taken or construed as a legal opinion or as legal advice!</sup>

Comment: I'm glad you added the warning.  I am not a lawyer, either, but I know that the law does not criminalize the awareness (or lack thereof) of circumstances.  Laws on criminal negligence speaks to awareness of risk.  I see the possible complement to *risk* in "a risk that we won't finish the job on time", but that's different:  there's no *it* for which *risk* is an antecedent.  It still seems like a restrictive modifier to me, though.

Comment: @deadrat I think the point is that the circumstance or result is already the thing percieved as being at fault for which somebody is percieved as being potentially accountable for because of their recklessness. If you read the second sentence with the parallel wording it is obvious that a 'risk' cannot "occur"  - or so it seems to me.

Comment: I'll have to agree that it's idiomatic to say that circumstances occur while risks exist, but the OP's example does not use the word *occur*.  Of course, now I've read the original so many times that I can't make sense of any of it.  One problem I find with your interpretation is "will exist" referring to "a circumstance."  The law expects you to make a reasonable projection into the future as regards possible risk.  Circumstances, not so much, unless this means "circumstances of risk," which seems unlikely.

Comment: I'd be happier if there were a comma after *circumstance* and after *result*; but I think you've got this right. I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the sentence a bit by by ignoring the phrase "with respect to a circumstance."  *With respect to* may be considered a compound preposition meaning *about*, and its object is *circumstance*.  The phrase makes no different either syntactically or semantically -- all actions concern some circumstance.

The problem arises when we consider the subordinate clause "that it exists or will exist."  We are expecting a restrictive relative clause modifying *risk*, that is, a clause that will tell us what kind of risk the reckless person is aware of.  In that case, the relative pronoun *that* serves as an element in the clause (here, the subject) and it associated with an **antecedent**, here **risk**.  Thus we expect

> when he is aware of a **risk** *that* exists or [*that*] will exist

But that's not what we get.  Instead we get what some grammars call a content clause that ordinarily functions as something other than a modifier in the main clause.  For example, as an **object**:

> when is aware of a risk and knows **that it exists or will exist**.

Notice that the subordinate clause serves not as a modifier but as the complement to the verb *knows*, telling us what it is that the reckless person knows.  Note also that the relative pronoun has no antecedent.  Instead the subject of the subordinate clause, *it*, is the one linked to the antecedent *risk*.

Comment: Great.  Someone unwilling or unable to articulate a problem with the answer, a driveby downvoter, a curse on this site.

Comment: Not my downvote. I think your answer is great! However,  I don't think your interpretation is correct. I've given my point of view below, what to you think?

Answer (score 0):

"A person acts recklessly within the meaning of section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act of 1971 with respect to a circumstance when that [or this] person is aware of a risk that exists or will exist."
Nothing wrong with it now...Not difficult to fix at all.

Comment: You were asked whether the grammar is correct, not to correct the grammar.

Comment: The only way I know to show that grammar is incorret is to correct it. "with respect to a circumstance" is crucial to the meaning of the sentence. If it is removed the sentence falls part. The OP incorrectly parsed the sentence.

Comment: @Lambie but the grammar is already correct! :)

Comment: No, it is not correct. Here is how it was written by the OP:  "when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist."

Comment: @Lambie Exactly so. The *that* is not a relative *that*. It is introducing a content clause. The clause means *when he is aware of a risk that that circumstance exists or will exist*.